# How to manage multiple operations using threads/thread pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I need to create an application that performs multiple actions in parallel. I was thinking about using threads or thread pool, but I have never worked with this before so I find it quite difficult.
The threads should work the following way:

```
MainSystem -> get average of the 3 systems below
----System 1 -> perform increment/decrement
----System 2 -> get average of the 3 subsystems below
--------3 subsystems -> each system perform increment/decrementindependently
----System 3 -> get average of the 15 subsystems below
--------15 subsystems -> each system perform increment/decrement independently
```

All systems should perform at the same time. How do you think I should implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?  You could make use of parallelism:

```
Parallel.ForEach(calculations, (currentCalc) => 
{
    // perform calculation
});
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Please provide more details on the actual calculations you need to perform.

Comment: It is only a simple increment/decrement operation that I need. I didn't even know about this, but I think it will work like charm. Thank you!

Comment: What do I do to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: Where are you getting a deadlock?  Please show some code.

Comment: It's alright now. I thought it was a deadlock, but it was something else.